# Transformation and filldown on large set of vertical data in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have around 100000 lines of data im trying to transform, to be able to search it like a database for another sheet in my workbook.

Currently my data is structured in blocks for each ID, with a bunch of blank lines going down before a total line. My goal is to fill down the first four cells into this blank space until it hits the total row, and then to remove the total row completely and the session end column and time column. So I end up with lots of entries for each ID and I can search the entire range by multiple criteria.

The current data looks like this repeating with various block lengths for 100k rows

Example image

[image: 1]

My goal is to transform it into something like this:

Goal Design

[image: 2]

I've tried to remove each row containing the "Totals for" cell however im lost when it comes to automating the filldowns for the ID, Surname, First Name and Tier Cells.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Please create MD table with online tool [Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables).

Comment: ... or use this [VBA code](https://davetallett26.github.io/excel-markdown.html) to create a Markdown table from Excel and edit it into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.SpecialCells method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144203)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Range.AutoFilter method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim lastRow As Long, oSht As Worksheet, dataRng As Range, visRng As Range
    Set oSht = ActiveSheet ' modify as needed
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Show all data on sheet
    If oSht.AutoFilterMode Then
        If oSht.AutoFilter.FilterMode Then
            oSht.ShowAllData
        End If
    End If
    lastRow = oSht.Cells(oSht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set dataRng = oSht.Range("A2:D" & lastRow)
    With dataRng
        ' Fill blank with formulas
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="
        Set visRng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        If Not visRng Is Nothing Then visRng.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
        Set visRng = Nothing
        ' Remove Totals rows
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Totals for"
        Set visRng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        If Not visRng Is Nothing Then visRng.EntireRow.Delete
        ' Convert formulas to value
        .Formula = .Value
        .AutoFilter
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm receiving the error "Object variable or with block variable not set" at the line "If oSht.AutoFilter.FilterMode Then"